# Intuition behind permutations + probability

Tags: probability, self-study, permutation-test, permutation

I'm new to stats so I'm struggling to grasp the intuition behind permutations + probability. Would anybody be able to help me with parts (b) and (c) of this question?

Any help is greatly appreciated :)

> A game requires you to match 10 words to 10 images (where each word
> correctly labels only one image). A machine randomly matches
> each word to a different image, where all possible labellings are
> equally likely.
>
> What is the probability that the machine matches:
>
> - (a) all 10 words correctly?
> - (b) the first 7 words correctly?
> - (c) exactly 9 of the 10 words correctly?

This question is from a stats class problem set.

My work so far:

- (a) $\frac{1}{10!}$ as $10!$ permutations are possible with only 1 having all correctly matched.
- (b) I think $\frac{10!}{3!}$ but not 100% sure.
- (c) Not too sure where to begin but I realise that if the last word is incorrectly matched then one of the 9 must also be incorrectly matched. What is the question instead said exactly 8 correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- How many equally likely permutations are there?
- How many permutations get all $10$ words correct? What proportion of the total is this?
- How many permutations get the first $7$ words correct and the last $3$ in any order? What proportion of the total is this?
- If exactly $9$ out of $10$ words are correct then $1$ word is matched to a wrong image.  What might have happened to the other word that should have been matched to that image?

Comment: Thanks! Here's what I've got so far.
• $10!$ permutations possible
• $\frac{1}{10!}$ permutations gets all 10 correct
• $\frac{10!}{7!}$ get the first 7 correct?
• Not too sure for the last one

Comment: $\frac{1}{10!}$ is correct.  $\frac{10!}{7!}$ is not: if the first seven are correct, then you are counting the number of permutations of the last three.  The final question has two possible answers: either the other word was matched correctly or it was matched incorrectly, and each of those has logical implications

Comment: Right so $\frac{10!}{7!}$ should be $\frac{10!}{3!}$ and for the last one if it was matched incorrectly then that means it isn't possible to have the other 9 be correct - what if the question was instead asking about matching exactly 8 out of 10 correctly?

Comment: You might want to read about [rencontres numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)